# PHP Find and replace a part of string

Tags: php, string, replace

I have an input string. Format is below:

```
This;is;my;long;string
```

Any fast solution (a lot of strings) to get this output string using PHP:

```
This;is;my;long
```

I need to remove this appendix: `;string`

- I don't know the length of appendix: ;any letters here.

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?  Also, [what are you *really* trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ';'));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're consistently using `;` as the delimiter, you can `explode()` the string, remove the last index, then rejoin the string using `implode()`:

```
$str    = "This;is;my;long;string";
$strArr = explode(";", $str);

unset($strArr[count($strArr) - 1]);
$newStr = implode(";", $strArr);
```

**UPDATE**

In order to make this work for *any* searchable string, you can use `array_keys()`:

```
$str             = "This;is;my;long;string";
$strArr          = explode(";", $str);
$searchStr       = "string";
$caseSensitive   = false;
$stringLocations = array_keys($strArr, $searchStr, $caseSensitive);

foreach ($stringLocations as $key) {
    unset($strArr[$key]);
}
$newStr = implode(";", $strArr);
```

Or, even quicker, you can use `array_diff()`:

```
$str       = "This;is;my;long;string";
$strArr    = explode(";", $str);
$searchStr = array("string");
$newArray  = array_diff($searchStr, $strArr);
$newStr    = implode(";", $newArray);
```

Comment: @Fluffeh I realized that was going to come up, so I updated the answer.

Comment: don't use implode/explode since it will be too slow.

Answer (score 2):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php 
$string='This;is;my;long;string';
str_replace(';string','',$string); ?>
```

Comment: This is a bit short-sighted. It will only work for this case.

Comment: You can adjust the first parameter of str_replace with whatever you need to replace, using a string or array of strings. The question doesn't state the end case, is it always the last element, is it always delimited by ';' - he wanted ;string removing, this does it and can be easily adapted to most other situations.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = rtrim($str, ';string');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `;string` will always be there (most of the time anyhow) you can use rtrim:

```
$trimmed = rtrim($text, ";string");
```

This will remove only the trailing `;string` from the string. Unless it exists on the end of the string , it won't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the piece you want to remove is consistently at the beginning or not.

```
$array = explode(";" , $string);
foreach ( $array as $key => $arr ) {
    if ( $arr == "string" ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        break;
    }
    echo implode(";" , $array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always formatted that way you can't go wrong with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - probably the fastest way

```
$str = 'This;is;my;long;string';
$str = substr( $str, 0, -7);
```

Comment: This is a bit short-sighted. It will only work for this case.

Comment: i know, but maybe that's what he wanted. he mentioned speed, and substr is faster than str_replace