# Replace 'New Line' with '|'

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How can I replace new line with |?

Let's say that I have these:

```
$strPar = "12345|12345|12345|12345
12345|12345|12345|12345
12345|12345|12345|12345";
```

And I want it to be like these:

```
$strPar = "12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345|12345";
```

Comment: $strPar=str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array('','|'),$strPar);

Comment: -1 because `str_replace` is the first result when googling "php replace".

Comment: or even [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282261/php-find-and-replace-a-part-of-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$strPar = "12345|12345|12345|12345
    12345|12345|12345|12345
    12345|12345|12345|12345";

$strpar = str_replace("\n", "|", $strPar);
```

Make sure the `\n` character is in double quotes

Comment: or the PHP_EOL constant can be used to be sure that the new line symbol is matched for any operating system..

Comment: @mishu, +1 thats true as well, `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '|', $strpar);`

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = str_replace("\n", "|", $string);
$string = str_replace("\r", "|", $string);
```

Comment: this achieves exactly what Phil suggested only its more cumbersome and grows memory. Sorry i have to downvote it

Comment: Not to mention that if the lines are actually terminated by `\r\n` you get two pipe characters per line break.

Comment: Actually Juhana, `\r\n` is unique to windows os line termination. So this could be potentially useful but it still grows memory unnecessarily

Comment: @BrandtSolovij My point exactly: if you use this code in Windows server, the result is `"12345||12345"`.

Comment: ahh gotcha - OP didn't add environment spec so the iterative string recreation is where the bulk of my concern is